# Static class member not calling constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class Temp {
 public:
  static Temp temp;

  Temp() { std::cout << "hi!"; }
};

int main() {}
```

Suprisingly, "hi" is not printed. I checked the assembly and it omitted the construction of `temp`.

What's the condition to make sure the static class member's constructor to be called properly?

---

Additional Question:

Why is the behavior different for the templated class?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Temp {
 public:
  static Temp temp;

  Temp() { std::cout << "hi!"; }
};

int main() { Temp<int> i; }
```

It shows "hi" properly.

Comment: The static member is declared, but not defined anywhere, so there is no object to construct (and no code references it, otherwise you'd get a link error). Define it like `Temp Temp::temp;` outside the class and you'll see the constructor fire.

Comment: @dxiv Hi thanks for the comment. Just one more question. Why is the behavior different for the templated class?

Comment: It's not different. The one and only constructor call comes from the `Temp<int> i;` in `main`. Replace it with `int main() { auto &n = Temp<int>::temp; }` and see what happens.

Comment: @dxiv ahh i was dumb :p

Answer (score 0):

"Hi" would be not printed because there is no instance of the class.

```
int main() 
{
    Temp temp;
}
```

It'll works. (template has no connection with it)

Answer (score 0):

> Suprisingly, "hi" is not printed. I checked the assembly and it
> omitted the construction of temp.

The constructor is not called because there are no objects being constructed.

> shows "hi" properly

Because an object is constructed, the constructor is called.

> What's the condition to make sure the ctor of the static member of the
> class to be called properly

The static member cannot be constructed but is initialized. The static member(only the member, not the object of the class it belongs to) exists even before main() function is entered. In your class you only declared a static member but haven't defined it.

You will need to define and initialize the static member.

See here

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static